# How I can draw an existent Canvas on another Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, transparency, paint

Now I need to draw a new `Canvas` in an existent `Canvas` (the *parent `Canvas`*), like `Bitmap`'s works.
The logic is this:

- Each `Sprite` *can* have others `Sprite` nodes (`LinkedList<Sprite> nodes`);
- If don't have nodes (`nodes = null`) then, will draw the `(Bitmap) Sprite.image` directly to parent canvas, received on `update` method, like (*currently working*):

  ```
  public void update(Canvas canvas){
      if(this.nodes == null){
          canvas.drawBitmap(this.image, ...);
      }
      ...
  }
  ```
- If it have nodes, I need create a new `Canvas`, draw nodes bitmap on this, and draw the new `Canvas` on parent `Canvas`. This don't works, but the idea is like this:

  ```
  public void update(Canvas canvas){
      ...
      else { // this.nodes != null
          Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas();

          for(Sprite node: this.nodes){
              node.update(newCanvas);
          }

          // Canvas working like Bitmap! (?)
          canvas.drawCanvas(newCanvas, this.x, this.y, this.paint);
      }
  }
  ```

**Real example usage**: well, I have a `Sprite` called `CarSprite`. The `CarSprite` have a private class called `WheelSprite extends Sprite`. The `CarSprite` implements two nodes (*two dimensional example*) of `WheelSprite`, that will be positioned in the `CarSprite` to seems the whell of car. So far, no problem.

But if `CarSprite` is affected by a devil one object in the level, this will be turn *transparent*. I will do, for instance, `objectOfCarSprite.paint.setAlpha(127);`. The problem is, if I do it (*currently working mode*), only the car bitmap will turn transparent, but not the well, because it is drawed *directly* to global `Canvas` object.

**This part does not influence much**: currently, I'm getting the parent (of parentN...) `Paint` object alpha, and with some math, I get a transparent solution to wheel that works almost as well I need, but if, for instance, the `WheelSprite` object is over car bitmap, is possible to see the *ground* of car, like picture.

Exists a better way to do *like I want*, or only *like work currently*?

[image: Example]

Comment: Draw a white 100% opaque "mask" first?

Comment: How you think that I can do that? I don't get your tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it. But is very slow, but works fine.

```
    final Bitmap split = Bitmap.createBitmap(GameActivity.screenWidth,
        GameActivity.screenHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas subCanvas = new Canvas(split);

    for(final Sprite sprite: this.nodes) {
        sprite.update(subCanvas);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(split, this.x, this.y, this.paint);
```

1. First we need have a `Canvas` object (here just `canvas`);
2. After, we need make a `Bitmap` where we will draw. This need get a `width` and `height` from current `canvas`. I used a shortcut on this case;
3. Next, we need make a new `Canvas`, it will be passed to `Sprite.nodes`;
4. After all, we need draw the bitmap on global canvas;

**Note**: this works very well, but affect to much the speed.